Analysis of Derivatives in a Sequence of Concave Functions
Consider a sequence $\{h_n(t)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of concave functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Each function $h_n$ in the sequence is differentiable at $t = 0$. We know the following about the sequence:

Assume for $t \in [-1, 1]$, the sequence satisfies $\liminf_{n \to \infty} h_n(t) \geq t^3 + 3$.
The limit of $h_n(0)$ as $n \to \infty$ is exactly 3.

I am interested in determining $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n'(0)$.
Here is my initial analysis: The derivative of the bounding function $p(t) = t^3 + 3$ at $t = 0$ is $3t^2$. Evaluating this at $t = 0$, we find that $p'(0) = 0$.
Given the condition $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(t) \geq p(t)$, and knowing $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(0) = 3$, we meet this lower limit at $t = 0$ as $p(0) = 3$.
For concave functions $h_n(t)$, the derivative $h_n'(t)$ is non-increasing. Employing the concavity property, for any two points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and any $\lambda \in [0, 1]$:
$$
h_n(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda h_n(x) + (1-\lambda)h_n(y). 
$$
Applying this at $t=0$ and some small $t$, with $\lambda = 1/2$, yields:
$$
h_n(t/2) \geq \frac{1}{2} h_n(t) + \frac{1}{2} h_n(0). 
$$
Given the asymptotic behavior of $h_n(t)$ as $t$ approaches zero and the known limit at $t=0$, we may consider what $h_n'(0)$ could be converging to, considering $p'(0) = 0$. The derivative at $t=0$ for $h_n$ seems potentially influenced by the behavior of $p(t)$ near $t=0$.
Could there be a formal way to determine if $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n'(0) = p'(0) = 0$ based on these properties, or is there a more rigorous exploration into the behavior of concave functions that might be required?

This doesn't seem possible. The derivative of $t^3 + 3$ grows without bound whereas each concave function $h_n(t)$ derivative is bounded (due to non-increasing). So $t^3 + 3$ will surpass each of the $h_n(t)$ eventually. So I am suspicious if $t^3 + 3$ can lower bound the sequence of concave functions

@balddraz I am sorry for the confusion regarding the problem statement. I made them a bit clearer now.

@balddraz Actually, you might be right about the non-existence of such concave functions, but I believe calculating the derivative at zero still should be possible imo.

If $f_n$ are concave, then $\liminf_n f_n$ is concave.. Since any (real valued) concave function is majorised by an affine function, we see that the $\liminf_n$ cannot lie above $t \mapsto t^3+3$ everywhere.

Not sure what I was consuming when I wrote the answer below.

@Snowball If such functions don't exist, then vacuously you can prove anything about them. Falsity implies any result you want.

@copper.hat I terribly apologize for my typos. I changed the problem statement with interval $[-1, 1]$

@balddraz Now the updated version should be correct.

Let $h = \liminf_n h_n$. Suppose $L=\lim_k h_{n_k}'(0)$ exists (that is, a limit exists over some subsequence). We also have $\lim_k h_{n_k}(0)=3$. Since $h_{n_k}$ is concave we have
$h_{n_k}(x) \le h_{n_k}(0)+h_{n_k}'(0)x$.
Then we have $p(x) \le h(x) \le \lim_k h_{n_k}(0) + \lim_k h_{n_k}'(0)x = 3+Lx$, which is impossible.

I might be wrong, but what I understand from this solution that you only proved $h(x)$ to be non-finite for positive $x$. How does this relate to the limit of the derivative at $t=0$?

Slightly refined answer.

Thank you for editing the answer but I really can'y understand how you prove these properties, especially. $h_{n_k}(x) \leq h_{n_k}(0)+h_{n_k}^{\prime}(0) x$. Similar reasoning goes for the last line. Can you please be more elaborative for proving these in detailed?

The first is a standard property of convex/concave functions (if $f$ is concave, then $f(x) \le f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$ for all $x,y$). The last line follows because you are given that $p \le h$ and $\liminf_n h_n \le \lim_k h_{n_k}$ by definition.

Just to be clear, this shows that there is no sequence $h_n$ satisfying the conditions, echoing @balddraz's comment to the question.
